# Problema calculos en formulario

Tags: javascript, html, calculo

llevo mas de una semana con este problema y no se como darle solucion, soy novato en esto de la programacion y acudo aqui para ver si me podeis ayudar y aprender.
Tengo que hacer un calculo en un presupuesto para mi pagina web ficticia, con una aplicacion del 5% por cada mes de plazo con un maximo del 20%. El presupuesto se tiene que actualizar a medida que se realice algun cambio.
He intentado introducir algunos ejemplos que he visto pero me es imposible realizarlo. Les indico el codigo que estoy utilizando aver si me podeis echar una mano

```
    <body>
    <header>   
        </header>
        
    <section>
<!--Div que tiene todo el contenido de la pagina principal-->
            <div id="div_seccion_principal">
            <article>
                <header>
                    <div id=""><h1>Formulario de Inscripción</h1></div>
                </header>                
            </article>
<!-- Div y Script formulario -->
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Datos:</h1>
                </header>
                <div id="formulario"></div>
                <form action="http://foo.com" method="post">
                <header>
                    <h5>Nombre</h5>
                </header>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="caja_gris" maxlength="50" size="40" id="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="Nombre (requerido)" required /></input>
                <div id="boton_form"></div>
                <header>
                    <h5>Apellidos</h5>
                </header>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="caja_gris" maxlength="50" size="40" id="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="Nombre (requerido)" required /></input>
                <div id="boton_form"></div>
                <header>
                    <h5>Telefono movil</h5>
                </header>
                <input type="text" name="telefono" class="caja_gris" maxlength="50" size="40" id="TELEFONO" value="" placeholder="Telefono (requerido)" required /></input>
                <div id="boton_form"></div>
                <header>
                    <h5>E-mail</h5>
                </header>
                <input type="text" name="e-mail" class="caja_gris" maxlength="50" size="40" id="E-MAIL" value="" placeholder="Direccion@correo.com (requerido)" required /></input>
                <div id="boton_form"></div>
                <header>
                    <h1>La web:</h1>
                </header>
                <header>
                    <h5>Tipo de pagina web</h5>
                </header>
                <select name="Tipo de pagina">
                    <option value="100">Basico </option> 
                    <option value="200">Neutro</option> 
                    <option value="300">Avanzado</option>
                </select>
                <header>
                    <h5>Plazo en meses</h5>
                </header>
                <input type="number" name="plazo en meses" class="caja_gris" maxlength="50" size="40" id="MESES" value="0,5" /></input>
                <header>
                    <h5>Marque las selecciones deseadas</h5>
                </header>
                <p>
                    Galeria de fotos: <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="40" />
                    Quienes somos: <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="40" />
                    Donde estamos: <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="40" />
                    eComerce: <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="40" />
                    Gestion interna: <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="40" />
                    Noticias: <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="40" />
                    Facebook: <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="40" />
                    Twiter: <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="40" />
                </p>
                <input type="number" name="Total" id="Total" value="0" >
                <input type="submit" name="Boton de enviar" value="ENVIAR FORMULARIO" class="boton_form morado" /></input>
                <input type="reset" name="Boton de borrado" value="BORRAR FORMULARIO" class="boton_form morado" /></input>
                </header>
            </article>
                </div>
    </section>

</body>
```

y este es el script que use la ultima vez, pero he usado unos cuantos ya sin exito.

```
<script>
        function sumar(opcion){
    if (opcion==1) {
      var suma =   parseInt($('#Tipo de pagina').val()) +  parseInt($('#selection').val());
      $('#Subtotal1').val(suma);
      var resta =   parseInt($('#Subtotal1').val()) -  parseInt($('#Subtotal2').val());
      $('#Total').val(suma2);
    }else if (opcion == 2) {
      var multiplicacion =   parseInt($('#Subtotal1').val()) *  parseInt($('#plazo en meses').val());
      $('#Subtotal2').val(suma1);
      var resta2 =   parseInt($('#Subtotal1').val()) -  parseInt($('#Subtotal2').val());
      $('#Total').val(suma3);
    }
       }
    </script>
```

Si me podeis echar una mano lo agradeceria. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los ID y nombres de campo no deben tener espacios, por ejemplo `<select name="Tipo de pagina">` debería ser algo como `<select name="Tipo_de_pagina">` y, como no tiene ID, debes acceder con `$('select[name="Tipo_de_pagina"]')`. Por otra parte, los _checkboxes_ tienen todos el mismo nombre y se van a sobreescribir, quedando solo el último disponibe, a menos que les agregues corchetes: `<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="40">`, pero se deben manejar como arreglos.

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es tener muy claro cómo funcionan los selectores (ID, clase, nombre, etc.), tanto en HTML como en jQuery. Finalmente, no incluiste el código con el que ejecutas la función `sumar()`.